# What's the source that Rabbi Akiva's students stopped passing away on Lag BaOmer?

Tags: sources-mekorot, masechet-yevamot, lag-ba-omer

The source of Rabbi Akiva's students passing away during Sefira is from the Gemara in Yevamos 62b

> רבי יהושע אומר נשא אדם אשה בילדותו ישא אשה בזקנותו היו לו בנים בילדותו יהיו לו בנים בזקנותו שנא' בבקר זרע את זרעך ולערב אל תנח ידך כי אינך יודע אי זה יכשר הזה או זה ואם שניהם כאחד טובים ר"ע אומר למד תורה בילדותו ילמוד תורה בזקנותו היו לו תלמידים בילדותו יהיו לו תלמידים בזקנותו שנא' בבקר זרע את זרעך וגו' אמרו שנים עשר אלף זוגים תלמידים היו לו לרבי עקיבא מגבת עד אנטיפרס וכולן מתו בפרק אחד מפני שלא נהגו כבוד זה לזה והיה העולם שמם עד שבא ר"ע אצל רבותינו שבדרום ושנאה להם ר"מ ור' יהודה ור' יוסי ורבי שמעון ורבי אלעזר בן שמוע והם הם העמידו תורה אותה שעה תנא כולם מתו מפסח ועד עצרת

The Gemara clearly says that they died from Pesach until Atzeres (Shavuos). Where did Lag BaOmer come from?

Comment: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9C%22%D7%92_%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8#.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.A7.D7.AA_.D7.94.D7.9E.D7.95.D7.95.D7.AA_.D7.A9.D7.9C_.D7.AA.D7.9C.D7.9E.D7.99.D7.93.D7.99_.D7.A8.D7.91.D7.99_.D7.A2.D7.A7.D7.99.D7.91.D7.90

Comment: related to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26881/is-there-any-evidence-that-rabbi-akivas-students-fought-alongside-bar-kochba/28264#28264 and  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27768/rabbi-akivas-24k-students-died-because-of-interpersonal-issues-but-he-said-vea and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28240/why-celebrate-lag-baomer-on-the-33rd-according-to-the-maharil and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/372/feelings-of-mourning-during-sefirat-haomer and others...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sources are brought in the footnotes [here](http://ph.yhb.org.il/05-03-02/). On the specific question of where it comes from, several Rishonim write that this is a tradition from the Geonim (for example the Meiri on that Gemera). Some have a version of the Gemara that is "פרוס עצרת" - half way, in other words half a month, or 15 days, before Shavuos, which would be the 34th day of the Omer. This is what the Mechaber paskens like, but some claim that the intention isn't exact, and it means the day before.

There are additional reasons, given at the link. See also the discussion [here](http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=1019&cat=9&haoro=9).