# Did R' Akiva's students die in one year?

Tags: calendar, sefirat-ha-omer, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef

> שנים עשר אלף זוגים תלמידים היו לו לרבי עקיבא מגבת עד אנטיפרס וכולן מתו בפרק אחד מפני שלא נהגו כבוד זה לזה
>
> Rabbi Akiva had twelve thousand pairs of students in an area of land that stretched from Gevat to Antipatris in Judea, and they all died in one period of time, because they did not treat each other with respect. ([Yevomos 62](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yevamot.62b.9?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=en))

It says "one period" - is it "49 consecutive days of one year" or was it "one period in different years"?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/58971/whats-the-source-that-rabbi-akivas-students-stopped-passing-away-on-lag-baomer

Comment: Shulchan Aruch (OC 493:1) "until Lag Baomer" (not 49 days).

Answer (score 1):

I remember a theory that they really died during the bar Kochva revolt, which squares with the"one period" talmudic quote and the large number (a million Jews died).  This theory is consistent with the Talmud because Jewish teaching is that early deaths can be attributed to sinning.

Comment: Is there any evidence that Rabbi Akiva's students fought alongside Bar Kochba? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26881/is-there-any-evidence-that-rabbi-akivas-students-fought-alongside-bar-kochba

Comment: They could have died without fighting.

Comment: I agree. I just thought that it would be helpful to provide a source for the theory you heard/saw.

Answer (score 0):

Tashbetz (i:178) raises the possibility of when this period ended. It starts from Pesach, and ends (said in the name of Rabbi Zerachia Halevi in the name of some old sefardí book) at the ‘pras’ of Atezres. He discusses what exactly pras may refer to.

Kohelet Rabbah (11:6) says specifically from Pesach to Atezres.

Comment: So is it one year or in different years?

Comment: ‘From pesach to ateres’ I’ll be away from Tuesday till Friday- wait, Friday this year or in 2025??

Comment: I understand you. Just please add it to your answer. However in Hebrew, the text says "בפרק אחד" so if they all died on Omer but in 50 years it would still count as "in one specific period in the year". Because that's what the question exactly asked.

Comment: If it wanted to say fifty years, I think at least it would write in in a specific way.

Comment: Rashbi also died in "that period of time" - 33rd Baomer.

Comment: Netanyahu was born on the same day as George Washington. (He wasn’t).